# intersection of two columns of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 pandas dataframes: `dataframe1` and `dataframe2` that look like this:

```
mydataframe1
Out[15]: 
    Start   End  
    100     200
    300     450
    500     700


mydataframe2
Out[16]:
  Start   End       Value     
  0       400       0  
  401     499       -1  
  500     1000      1  
  1001    1698      1
```

Each row correspond to a segment (start-end).
For each segment in dataframe1 I would like to assign a value depending on the values assigned to the segments in dataframe2.

For example:

the first segment in dataframe1 `100 200` is included in the first segment of dataframe2 `0 400` then I should assign the value 0

the second segment in dataframe1 `300 450` is contained in the first `0 400` and second `401 499` segments of dataframe2. In this case I need to split this segments in 2 and assign the 2 corresponding values. ie `300 400 -> value 0` and `401 - 450 value ->-1`

the final dataframe1 should look like

```
mydataframe1
Out[15]: 
    Start   End  Value
    100     200  0
    300     400  0
    401     450  -1
    500     700  1
```

I hope I was claer..can you help me?

Comment: _"the second segment in dataframe1 300 350 is contained in the first 0 400 and second 401 499 segments of dataframe2"_... how is 300 to 350 contained in 401 to 499?

Comment: sorry... there was a typo

Comment: If your df1 rows were subsets of df2 rows, you can have used apply: df1.apply(lambda x: df2 .Value[(df2 ['Start'] <=x['Start']) & (df2 ['End'] >= x['End'])], axis=1) . However your problem is more complex, I'm afraid you need to loop and think about all the cases...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that there is a Pandas method that you can use to solve this directly.
You have to calculate the intersections manually to get the result you want. The [intervaltree](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/intervaltree/2.0.4) library makes the interval overlap calculation easier and more efficient at least.

`IntervalTree.search()` returns the (full) intervals that overlap with the provided one but does not calculate their intersection. This is why I also apply the `intersect()` function I have defined.

```
import pandas as pd
from intervaltree import Interval, IntervalTree

def intersect(a, b):
    """Intersection of two intervals."""
    intersection = max(a[0], b[0]), min(a[1], b[1])
    if intersection[0] > intersection[1]:
        return None
    return intersection

def interval_df_intersection(df1, df2):
    """Calculate the intersection of two sets of intervals stored in DataFrames.
    The intervals are defined by the "Start" and "End" columns.
    The data in the rest of the columns of df1 is included with the resulting
    intervals."""
    tree = IntervalTree.from_tuples(zip(
            df1.Start.values,
            df1.End.values,
            df1.drop(["Start", "End"], axis=1).values.tolist()
        ))

    intersections = []
    for row in df2.itertuples():
        i1 = Interval(row.Start, row.End)
        intersections += [list(intersect(i1, i2)) + i2.data for i2 in tree[i1]]

    # Make sure the column names are in the correct order
    data_cols = list(df1.columns)
    data_cols.remove("Start")
    data_cols.remove("End")
    return pd.DataFrame(intersections, columns=["Start", "End"] + data_cols)

interval_df_intersection(mydataframe2, mydataframe1)
```

The result is identical to what you were after.

Comment: intersections += [(*intersect(i1, i2), i2.data) for i2 in tree[i1]] 
gives invalid syntax

Comment: You appear to be using Python 2, which does not argument unpacking for lists etc. You can replace that with `intersections += [list(intersect(i1, i2)) + [i2.data] for i2 in tree[i1]]`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer... it seems to work fine. However, in case mydataframe2 has another column next to the one "value" containing strings the code gives an error... Would it be possible to have the same behaviour as for the column "value"? ie add also these info to mydataframe1

Comment: Not a bad idea to make it more general. I updated the code accordingly and   made it a bit tidier as well.

Comment: Hi Martin, if df1 contains an element with the same value in "Start" and "End"  intervalTree gives me an error... IntervalTree: Null Interval objects not allowed in IntervalTree
Do you know how to handle this case?

Comment: sorry, the above happens if mydataframe2 has the same value in start and end

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer using the [NCLS](https://github.com/biocore-ntnu/ncls) library. It does not do the splitting, but rather answers the question in the title and does so really quickly.

Setup:

```
from ncls import NCLS

contents = """Start   End
100     200
300     450
500     700"""

import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_table(StringIO(contents), sep="\s+")

contents2 = """Start   End       Value
0       400       0
401     499       -1
500     1000      1
1001    1698      1"""
df2 = pd.read_table(StringIO(contents2), sep="\s+")
```

Execution:

```
n = NCLS(df.Start.values, df.End.values, df.index.values)

x, x2 = n.all_overlaps_both(df2.Start.values, df2.End.values, df2.index.values)

dfx = df.loc[x]
# Start  End
# 0    100  200
# 0    100  200
# 1    300  450
# 2    500  700

df2x = df2.loc[x2]
# Start   End  Value
# 0      0   400      0
# 1    401   499     -1
# 1    401   499     -1
# 2    500  1000      1

dfx.insert(dfx.shape[1], "Value", df2x.Value.values)
# Start  End  Value
# 0    100  200      0
# 0    100  200      0
# 1    300  450     -1
# 2    500  700      1
```